# Unable to make NgTable work with AngularJs 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to integrate NgTable with angularjs 1.5 in a component-based architecture (so, no old-style controllers).

The NgTable controls (filter, icons for sorting) appear, but they don't seem to work at all, so they don't filter and don't sort.

Here's my code

--- **activity-list-module.js** ---

```
 angular.module('activityList', ['ngTable']);
```

--- **activity-list-component.js** ---

```
(function(){
'use strict';
angular.
  module('activityList').
  component('activityList', {
    templateUrl: "app/activity-list/activity-list.html",
    controller: ['NgTableParams', function (NgTableParams) {
        var self=this;

          self.activitiesForm=[{id:0,description:"att0"},{id:1,description:"att1"},{id:2,description:"att2"}];
          self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: self.activitiesForm});


    }]
  });
  })();
```

--- **activity.list.html** ----

```
  <div style="margin:20pt">
  <h3>Manage Activities</h3>
 <div style="margin:20pt">
<h3>Manage Activities</h3>
 <div class="row" style="margin-left:20pt" >
<table id="myViewTable" ng-table="$ctrl.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true" class="table actTable" style="width:95%;table-layout: fixed;" >
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="projectActivity in $ctrl.activitiesForm track by projectActivity.id">
<td data-title="'Id'">{{projectActivity.id}}</td> 
<td data-title="'description'" filter="{ description: 'text'}" sortable="'description'">{{projectActivity.description}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Of course the component is called using the tag `<activity-list></activity-list>` in another page.

I'm working with AngularJs 1.5.8 and ng-table 3.0.1.

I'm doing something wrong or there is an incompatibility between AngularJs >= 1.5 and ng-table ?

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/q7c9qDruAGPaAxvhuAvh)

PS In the last case, how can I do ? Is smarttable compatible with AngularJs 1.5 ?

Comment: Have you tried to debug? What is your console saying?

Comment: ..it says nothing ..

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working plnkr or jsbin...?

Comment: here it is http://plnkr.co/edit/q7c9qDruAGPaAxvhuAvh  (now you can find it in the question too)

Comment: I even tested without component style in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kufuvoh/edit?html,js,output) and still got the same output. Seems like a compatibility issue in ng-table with angular 1.5. Raise an issue in ng-table repo

Comment: ..so..no way it seems

Comment: see the solution.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After raised an issue in ng-table GIT repo i got a working example from the creator of ng-table and i could have a look.

The point is in the use of controller variables, instead of a $data variable generated by ng-table.
So, in the case of the 'new style' component the issue is solved changing

```
      <tr ng-repeat="projectActivity in $ctrl.activitiesForm track by projectActivity.id">
```

with

```
     <tr ng-repeat="projectActivity in $data track by projectActivity.id">
```

In the case of the "old Style" controller it's solved changing

```
     <tr ng-repeat="user in vm.data">
```

with

```
     <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
```

I don't like a lot this solution, because it add a kind of global, but it works.

**EDIT**

it works also using

`$ctrl.tableParams.data` (for Component Example) and `vm.tableParams.data` (for the Controller Example) which let me feel much better about.